# Why does Rails generate a SQL query for an "include?" call in a view but not in the console?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In my app a `Position` `has_many` `Questions`.  In my position edit view, I create a set of checkboxes by looping over an array of `Questions` and checking those that the current position already includes.

Looks like this:

```
- @questions.each do |question|
  = check_box_tag :question_ids, question.id, @position.questions.include?(question), name: 'position[question_ids][]', id: "question_check_#{question.id}"
  = label_tag "question_check_#{question.id}", question.text
```

I noticed loading this page took an unusually long time and my logs had these (I've snipped it for space):

```
LOG: duration: 827.370 ms statement: SELECT 1 FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "required_questions" ON "questions"."id" = "required_questions"."question_id" WHERE "required_questions"."position_id" IS NULL AND "questions"."id" = 1 ORDER BY account_id desc, "questions".id asc LIMIT 1

LOG: duration: 821.666 ms statement: SELECT 1 FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "required_questions" ON "questions"."id" = "required_questions"."question_id" WHERE "required_questions"."position_id" IS NULL AND "questions"."id" = 2 ORDER BY account_id desc, "questions".id asc LIMIT 1

LOG: duration: 713.379 ms statement: SELECT 1 FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "required_questions" ON "questions"."id" = "required_questions"."question_id" WHERE "required_questions"."position_id" IS NULL AND "questions"."id" = 3 ORDER BY account_id desc, "questions".id asc LIMIT 1
```

I tracked the problem to this code:

```
@position.questions.include?(question)
```

I thought this was a simple Array.include? check so I was surprised by my findings.  I was also surprised when I fixed it by adding an explicit `.to_a` call:

```
@position.questions.to_a.include?(question)
```

I was surprised a third time when I tested the original code in the Rails console and no SQL query was generated.

At this point I'm just curious - why did my original code generate a SQL query for each iteration when the same code in Rails console (albeit without the iteration and inside Rails console) did not?  Why didn't it just do an `Array.include?` check?

Comment: IIRC associations aren't real arrays, although that's only a partial reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `@position.questions` is not an array. It's actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. The problem is that the console actually behaves differently from your server application.

For example, in your console `position.questions` returns an array. That is because the console is actually evaluating this expression as `position.questions.all` which is equivalent to `position.questions.to_a`. In your server application the `to_a` or `all` is not called until you actually use the query. This is a good thing because it means you can continue to build up a query and it will only actually get executed when it's called.

For instance:

```
query = @position.questions
query.first
query.last
```

Will actually generate two queries that return two records in your server application because the `query` variable will be assigned an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of an `Array`. In your console this will generate a single query, but the query will load all of the questions into an `Array` and assign that to `query` and then select the first and last elements.

The `all`, `first`, `last`, `count` and even `include?` keywords are all triggers that actually execute the query, so in your application when you call `@position.questions.include?` you are executing a single query on the `@position.questions` relation. Adding the `to_a` causes this query to be executed immediately.